# Set style attribute of <span> in vuejs3 dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3

After I make an API call, I want to create  elements according to the response.
I want the background color of the span be determined by the response I get.
I create the span elements like this:

```
<span v-else class="a" v-bind:style="determineColorOfLine(response)">
   {{ response }}
```

And I have a function called determineColorOfLine inside of `methods`

```
determineColorOfLine(response){
   console.log(response)
   return ("background-color: " + response)
}
```

I expect to see the text "response" with the background color of the API request's response (e.g. "blue").
However, the background color does not change. When I inspect the span element, I see

```
style=""
```

but I would expect

```
style="background-color: blue"
```

In the console, I see the log "blue", so the method gets run. I don't see any errors.
Where is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an object:

```
determineColorOfLine(response){
   console.log(response)

   // Make an object here
   return {"background-color": response}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest solution and it works like a charm. It is also possible to add additional attributes like this: return `{"background-color": response, "color":"white"}`

Answer (score 2):

You're returning `style="background-color: blue"` and **binding it to the inline style** in effect creating the statement `style=style="background-color: blue"`

Instead, use `return 'background-color: ' + response;`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it according to your answer, but the problem persists. I also edited the code in the question above.

Comment: can you provide more code to show how `response` is assigned a value and eventually passed down to your method?  I have a feeling the asynchronous nature of your API call is causing a problem but I don't know exactly how you've set things up.  Without using any API calls and just a `data` property instead I made a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-forest-wmd2i1?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 1):

Use computed property

```
computed: {
    colorOfLine() {
        return { backgroundColor: this.response } 
    } 
}
```

```
<span :style="colorOfLine"...
```

If your `response` comes from a parent component, create a nested component for your `span` and pass `response` as a prop.

*ParentComponent.vue*

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(response, ind) in request.responses" 
            class="is-inline-block" :key="ind">
        <MyCustomSpan :response="response" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyCustomSpan from './MyCustomSpan.vue';

export default {
    inject: [ 'myService' ],
    data() {
        return {
            responses: []
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        this.responses = await this.myService.getResponses();
    },
    components: {
        'MyCustomSpan': MyCustomSpan
    }
}
</script>
```

*MyCustomSpan.vue*

```
<template>
    <span v-else class="a" :style="colorOfLine">
        {{ response }}
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [ 'response' ],
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    computed: {
        colorOfLine() {
            return { backgroundColor: this.response } 
        } 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When I try that, I get an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.response is undefined` error. This could be because `response` from my original question comes from the following parent element of the span element in the original question: 
`<div v-for="(response, ind) in request.responses" class="is-inline-block" :key="ind">`

Comment: Then create a component for your span with this computed property and pass the response as a prop. I will edit the answer.